# Как посмотреть разницу всех файлов между двух заданных соседних коммитов

Tags: git, git-diff, git-log

Как посмотреть полную разницу между двух заданных соседних коммитов Git? Коммиты где-то в глубине проекта.

И какая графическая утилита поможет вывести это в удобочитаемом виде вроде: список измененных файлов в дереве и при раскрытии изменения между каждым файлом?

Comment: GitK не подойдёт?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

посмотреть отличия в файлах между двумя состояниями, зафиксированными коммитами `xxx` и `yyy`, можно например, так:

```
$ git diff xxx yyy
```

адресовать коммиты можно [разными способами](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B8), чаще всего используют первые несколько знаков (5-6 обычно достаточно) хэша коммита. хэши можно увидеть, например, в выдаче команды `log`:

```
$ git log
commit b032ec26bf7b09c9c6554195b3469fa63ec22519
Author: автор
Date: дата
   описание коммита
...
```

т.е., для адресации данного коммита можно использовать, например, `b032ec`.

---

в качестве «мыше-интерфейса» можно воспользоваться, например, [программой `gitk`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17549542/4827341):

[image]